# iOS Ad-hoc Distribution updates

Tags: ios, release, adhoc

I am planning to distribute an app using Ad-Hoc Distribution using the steps outlined here:

http://aaronparecki.com/How_to_Distribute_your_iOS_Apps_Over_the_Air

But I was wondering how Ad-Hoc distribution handles updates. Will the app automatically check our server for updates, or do we have to re-direct the user to our server url to download it manually each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no in-built update process/service for Ad-Hoc distribution. You need to push the build and advise users yourself.  Have you looked at [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com)?

Comment: I'd only had a quick glance at TestFlight. I'll give it a proper look now :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your app can notify users via push notification. Just send a notification message which includes the link to updated IPA.

User sees notification, opens your app, goes to link you provided, downloads the new version. Update completed.

But there will be some side effects you need to handle, of course.

Comment: This is what I had originally planned. On start-up, the app checks to see if there is a new version. If there is, it pushes them to a website to download it. To me, this seems more simplistic than using something like TestFlight, but maybe I'm making an oversight?

Comment: If app checks if a new version exists on start-up, user never gets notified about new version unless the app is launched. but a push notification would do this.

Comment: @erkanyildiz : yes, but this is not a problem if the main reason for updating is to make sure that the user is always running the latest version of the app. We are currently considering glenns solution in an Enterprise distribution scenario where we do not want to spam the users with notifications of new versions, we only want to make sure that they run the latest version of the app as unobtrusive as possible (a totally silent update installation would be great :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

Ad-Hoc distribution essentially does not handle the process of checking for and updating the app.

One can create a service which has to do the following:

1. Provide an api to check for updates
2. Host the plist file of the update
3. Host the ipa of the update

In the app at appropriate location call the api to check for update and incase there is an update open the url for the plist like follows

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=<link to the update plist>]];
```

When installing the app like this, system UI seems like the application is newly getting installed but actually it behaves exactly like an update all the old data is retained by the system

I came across https://apptele.com they provide this kind of service to host your updates and sample code to check for the update and handle the user interface.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, updated the answer accordingly hope I got it right this time.